# Javafx - mouse coordinate transformation form inside node to top top subscene

Tags: java, 3d, javafx-8

In below code, I have a box added in scene. I am printing the mouse event coordinate. Coordinates are fine when I am not clicking on the box but as soon as I click on the box I get some different set of coordinate relative to some different node. I am trying to get the normalized coordinate, relative to scene only, even if I click on the box. I cant use me.getSceneX()/Y() and cant set box as mouse transparent. So how to carry out this transformation. Thanks.

```
public class PointConversion extends Application 
{   
    private final static Group worldRoot = new  Group();
    private final PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera(true);
    private final static Scene scene = new Scene(worldRoot, 1100, 800);

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) 
    {
        camera.setNearClip(1.0); 
        camera.setTranslateZ(-6000);
        camera.setFarClip(100000.0);
        worldRoot.getChildren().add(camera);

        scene.setCamera(camera);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        scene.setOnMousePressed(me ->
        {
            Point2D mousePoint = new Point2D(me.getX(), me.getY());

            if(!(me.getTarget() instanceof Scene))
            {
                PickResult pickResult = me.getPickResult();
                mousePoint = pickResult.getIntersectedNode().localToScene(mousePoint);
            }

            System.out.println("me.getSource() : " + me.getTarget() + " mousePoint:" + mousePoint);
        });

        final PhongMaterial blueMaterial = new PhongMaterial();
        blueMaterial.setDiffuseColor(Color.web(Color.CRIMSON.toString(), 0.25));
        blueMaterial.setSpecularColor(Color.web(Color.CRIMSON.toString(), 0.25));

        Box cubiod = new Box(500, 500, 500);
        cubiod.setMaterial(blueMaterial);
        worldRoot.getChildren().add(cubiod);    
    }
}
```

Comment: `MouseEvent.getX()` and `getY()` will give coordinates in the coordinate space of the node to which the listener was added. You can call `localToScene(...)` on the node in which you have the local coordinates to get the coordinates in the `Scene`'s coordinate system, and then `sceneToLocal(...)` on the subscene to transform those to the subscene's coordinate system.

Comment: If you want a more complete answer, I recommend you [edit] your question to include a [MCVE].

Comment: Thanks James_D, I've updated the my question and added the sample code.

Comment: Yeah, I have no idea at all why that is behaving the way it is...

Comment: Thank you so much for taking time to check the code and answering. I'll keep searching on it.